# In R Latent Variable Analysis understanding problem and get error Lavaan package

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

My problem statement is to identify the factors that affects net promoter score

I am using lavaan package testing with sample data

Below is the code

```
library(lavaan)
age=c(24,56,34)
weight=c(76,55,66)
nps=c(9,4,5)
df=c(age,weight,nps)
mat1=matrix(c(cov(abs(scale(df)))),3,3,byrow=TRUE)
mod2 <- "weight ~ age \n        weight ~ nps"
mod1 <- "nps ~ age \n        nps ~ weight"
mat1=matrix(c(cor(abs(scale(df)))),3,3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(mat1) <- rownames(mat1) <- c("age", "weight", "nps")
mod1fit <- sem(mod1, sample.cov = mat1, sample.nobs = 100)
```

From above example can anyone help in understanding `nobs[Number of Observations=100]`. Usually in ML observations says about number of rows but I don't know the meaning here of nobs parameter .

I have used below link to learn

https://www.jaredknowles.com/journal/2013/9/1/latent-variable-analysis-with-r-getting-setup-with-lavaan

When I run above code I get error as below

```
Error in lav_samplestats_icov(COV = cov[[g]], ridge = ridge, x.idx = x.idx[[g]],  : 
  lavaan ERROR: sample covariance matrix is not positive-definite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lavaan` manual (that you can access from within the R console via the command `?sem`) states that the argument `sample.nobs` refers to

> Number of observations if the full data frame is missing and only sample moments are given. For a multiple group analysis, a list or a vector with the number of observations for each group.

Considering the error message: I'm not really sure what you are trying to acchieve with that following line of code

```
mat1=matrix(c(cov(abs(scale(df)))),3,3,byrow=TRUE)
```

This however leads to a non-positive definite sample covariance matrix that looks like this

```
> mat1
       age weight nps
age      1      1   1
weight   1      1   1
nps      1      1   1
```

If `age`, `weight` and `nps` are factors (for which you have three observations each) then

```
mat1 <- cor(data.frame(age,weight,nps))
```

might produce the intended covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation tom. I have a problem statement i.e., I need to find the factors that are influencing for net promoter score going low and high. I have variables like age, weight,height,weather_data etc. I have seen the blog as mentioned in question which inspired me on Latent Variable Analysis to work on. What I am trying is I need to find the attributes which I term as factor for  net promoter score i.e going low and high . For that other than weight and age I need to check on all the attributes . Please let me know if any process i.e efficient

Comment: If latent variable modelling is a feasible approach for your question, is beyond me and might be better adressed to [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). However, using `mat1 <- cor(...)` (better use `cov(...)`), whereas `...` is your raw data frame, as proposed in my response, should be practible.

Comment: Thanks for answer and help Tom. Last question how do we determine nobs from this mod1fit <- sem(mod1, sample.cov = mat1, sample.nobs = 100). Should be take count of rows of each group [Target label] ?

Comment: nobs is only necessary when you have nothing but the covariance matrix. That is, If you have e.g. just `mat1` as input, `sem` expects some kind of information as to how many observations are represented by that covariance matrix. If you do have the raw data (as in your case), you can insert this into the `sem`-statement as `data = data.frame(age,weight,nps)` argument (instead of `sample.cov`); then you don't need the nobs statement since `nobs` will be derived from the number of rows in the `data` input.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the help